# Null text field values while sending form

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

My form, all fields are properly named and attributed, payload data is all correct when submitting the form data

```
<td>
   <form name='pageform[<%= i %>]' action='/page' method='POST' id='pageform[<%= i %>]' target='_self'> 
      <input name='phone' id='phone' type='hidden' value='<%= data[key].guest_phone_number %>'>
      <input name='readytxt' id='readytxt' type='hidden' value='0'>

        <%
                var name = data[key].guest_name;
        const [first, last] = name.toString().split(' ');

        %>

                <input name='fname' id='fname' type='hidden' value='<%=first %>'>//
                <input name='lname' id='lname' type='hidden' value='<%=last %>'>//When I inspect these fields data is first and last name from the split above
                  </td>
              
                  
                    <td style='width:20%;text-align: right;padding:3px'>
                        <input name='page' formID='pageform' type=submit value=Page onClick="pageftn('<%= data[key].guest_name %>')">
                   </form></td>
```

This passes the form data to a server to be used. The custnum and readin variables pass numbers, the name fields obviously text. When inspecting the values of those fields are in fact the first and last names that they should be.

```
var numb = document.forms.length;
   for (let h = 1; h <= numb; h++){
   const myform = 'pageform[' + h + ']'
   const form = document.getElementById(myform)

var custnum = +parms.phone; 
var readyin = +parms.readytxt;
var firstName = +parms.fname;
var lastName = +parms.lname;



var twilarray = [custnum, readyin, firstName, lastName];

io.emit('go', twilarray);

\\ this outputs socket receive: type "message", data "2["go",[1234567890,0,null,null]]"
```

My issue on is when the data arrives at the server it arrive [1234567890,0,null,null]
I get that the numbers are being converted to strings and text is an object.

My question is how to get fname and lname to pass the string data they contain

Comment: If I hardcode text into the firstName and lastName variables then the array fields are not null when the data comes across. So for some reason it seems like they are not getting the values from the form inputs, but the two other variables(custnum and readyin) are?

Comment: do you think it should be `form.phone` instead of `parms.phone` or some code is missing here in the example?

Comment: I tried this, still came across null, I will post an answer below as I figured out how to do this a different way, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the individual inputs, i pass the req.body

```
let data = req.body
    
io.emit('go', data);
```

And on the other side

```
socket.on('go',async (data) => {
    console.dir(data);
    main(data);
    
})
```

this will output all the form data to the console
in the main function I get the individual pieces of data by doing

```
let num = data.phone
let state = data.readytxt
let custname = data.fname + ' ' + data.lname
```